# running bwoken from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ios-ui-automation

We're trying to set up continuous integration test on our iOS project and running into some issue running broken from Jenkins.

The error we are getting is the following:

```
iphone  Add measurment from CNX.js
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/script.rb:55:in `run': Test Script Failed (Bwoken::ScriptFailedError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:86:in `popen3'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/script.rb:53:in `run'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1427:in `to_proc'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/simulator_runner.rb:21:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/simulator_runner.rb:21:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/script_runner.rb:33:in `execute_for_family'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/script_runner.rb:28:in `execute_in_simulator'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/script_runner.rb:27:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/script_runner.rb:27:in `execute_in_simulator'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/script_runner.rb:20:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/cli/test.rb:105:in `test'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/cli/test.rb:71:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/lib/bwoken/cli.rb:56
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bwoken-2.0.0.beta.2/bin/bwoken:3
    from /usr/bin/bwoken:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bwoken:19
Recording   cancelled : At least one target failed to launch; aborting run
Error Domain=com.apple.instruments Code=1 "Error Starting Recording" UserInfo=0x7fa5632b19f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error Starting Recording, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=At least one target failed to launch; aborting run}[m
Failed to start trace.[m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I think the important part is here:

```
Recording   cancelled : At least one target failed to launch; aborting run
mError Domain=com.apple.instruments Code=1 "Error Starting Recording" UserInfo=0x7fa5632b19f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error Starting Recording, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=At least one target failed to launch; aborting run}
```

I can't make sense of it right now, so any help is appreciated.
Thanks, olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WE got it running using the jenkins app (https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app). The issue is related to the fact that Jenkins runs as a deamon and thus does not have access to the window server. 
There might be another way around this (changing the Jenkins user type), but running jenkins as an app works for us